# How to modify indexof in javascript file for using on external site loaded files

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found a script i wanted to use , but its using indexof in the language and i am going to load stylesheets from an external site.

Here is the downloaded HTML file i am using for example

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylealt1.css" title="alternate 1" />
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylealt2.css" title="alternate 2" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="styleswitcher.js"></script>


    <a href="#" onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('default'); return false;"><img src="defaultstyle.jpg" alt="default style" /></a> 
    <a href="#" onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('alternate 1'); return false;"><img src="altstyle1.jpg" alt="alternate style 1" /></a> 
    <a href="#" onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('alternate 2'); return false;"><img src="altstyle2.jpg" alt="alternate style 2" /></a>
```

My stylesheets will be loaded from a different url like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="www.mysite.com/style.css" />
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="www.mysite.com/stylealt1.css" title="alternate 1" />
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="www.mysite.com/stylealt2.css" title="alternate 2" />
```

How can the "styleswitcher.js" file be altered so this works when loading external stylesheets for default and alternate , i'm assuming the use of indexof , need substituted.

```
function setActiveStyleSheet(title) {
  var i, a, main;
  for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
    if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1 && a.getAttribute("title")) {
      a.disabled = true;
      if(a.getAttribute("title") == title) a.disabled = false;
    }
  }
}

function getActiveStyleSheet() {
  var i, a;
  for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
    if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1 && a.getAttribute("title") && !a.disabled) return a.getAttribute("title");
  }
  return null;
}

function getPreferredStyleSheet() {
  var i, a;
  for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
    if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1
       && a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("alt") == -1
       && a.getAttribute("title")
       ) return a.getAttribute("title");
  }
  return null;
}

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
  }
  else expires = "";
  document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
  }
  return null;
}

window.onload = function(e) {
  var cookie = readCookie("style");
  var title = cookie ? cookie : getPreferredStyleSheet();
  setActiveStyleSheet(title);
}

window.onunload = function(e) {
  var title = getActiveStyleSheet();
  createCookie("style", title, 365);
}

var cookie = readCookie("style");
var title = cookie ? cookie : getPreferredStyleSheet();
setActiveStyleSheet(title);
```

Comment: Which of the `indexOf`s do you not like?

Comment: any that are not allowing me to link external stylesheets instead of stylesheets within same index directory

Comment: Your question does not make sense. What is expected behaviour and what is actual behaviour? Console.log or network errors

Comment: the script switches between alternate stylesheets , but those stylesheets must be in same directory of the index html file. I want to load the stylesheets from another website

Comment: Found here - https://css-tricks.com/examples/AlternateStyleSheets/   , instead of having the stylesheets on same website , i have to load them from another website.

Comment: Why would that be a problem? The indexOf is looking at the REL attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing `indexOf`, which [is a `method` on the `string prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), with directory indexes, which are completely unrelated.

As-is, there is nothing in the JS that you posted that will prevent you from using it with external stylesheets. In fact, here is an example I threw together that shows it being used two externally hosted stylesheets:

```js
function toggleStyles() {
 var activeStylesheetTitle = getActiveStyleSheet();
 var toggleTo = activeStylesheetTitle === 'Bootstrap' ? 'Materialize' : 'Bootstrap';
 setActiveStyleSheet(toggleTo);
}
function setActiveStyleSheet(title) {
 var i, a, main;
 for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
  if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1 && a.getAttribute("title")) {
   a.disabled = true;
   if(a.getAttribute("title") == title) a.disabled = false;
  }
 }
}

function getActiveStyleSheet() {
 var i, a;
 for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
  if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1 && a.getAttribute("title") && !a.disabled) return a.getAttribute("title");
 }
 return null;
}

function getPreferredStyleSheet() {
 var i, a;
 for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
  if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1
  && a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("alt") == -1
  && a.getAttribute("title")
  ) return a.getAttribute("title");
 }
 return null;
}

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
 if (days) {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
 }
 else expires = "";
 document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
 var nameEQ = name + "=";
 var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
 for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
  var c = ca[i];
  while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
  if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
 }
 return null;
}

window.onload = function(e) {
 var cookie = readCookie("style");
 var title = cookie ? cookie : getPreferredStyleSheet();
 setActiveStyleSheet(title);
}

window.onunload = function(e) {
 var title = getActiveStyleSheet();
 createCookie("style", title, 365);
}

var cookie = readCookie("style");
var title = cookie ? cookie : getPreferredStyleSheet();
setActiveStyleSheet(title);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" title="Bootstrap" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" title="Materialize" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" />
<div style="font-size:20px; text-align:center; margin-bottom:10px; background-color:red; color:white; text-decoration: underline;" onclick="toggleStyles()">Click me to toggle stylesheets</div>
<button>Button Example</button>
<p>Paragraph Text Example: </p>
<select class="browser-default">
 <option>Option A</option>
 <option>Option B</option>
</select>
<p>Input field example:</p>
<div class="input-field">
 <input type="text" value="type in me!" />
</div>
```